# How to print values of void pointer if data types are unknown?

Tags: c++, pointers

Suppose someone gave me to Implement the print function to print the value of keys.Here two keys are given in parameter as key and key1.If i know the data type which are pointing by void pointer i can print following way.**But if i don't know the data type how will i print?**

```
void Print(map<string , void*>&mp,string key,string key1) {
    auto res =mp[key];
    auto res1 =mp[key1];
    cout<<*(string*)res<<endl;
    cout<<*(int*)res1<<endl;

}
```

For clarification main function is given below.

```
int main(){
    map<string , void*>mp;
    string *val = new string("val");
    mp["key"]=val;
    int *value = new int(5);
    mp["key1"]=value;
    Print(mp,"key","key1");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just, you can use polymorphism here,  don't use `void *`, create an interface (An interface in C++ is a normal class/struct with abstract methods) called `Printable` for example, then make your `map` as this `map<std::string, std::reference_wrapper<Printable>>` or `map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Printable>>` or `map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Printable>>`, or even map a string to raw pointer of Printable (not recommended).  Make your class have a virtual `printableString` function, then make a friend `operator <<` function to `ostream` where you can `cout << printableString()`

Comment: @user9335240: Please use answer section to answer because comments can be removed anytime.

Comment: @JeJo used the answer section and had a downvote

Answer (score 1):

> But if i don't know the data type how will i print?

It is impossible to recover the data types from only a `void*`. You will have to find another way.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `map` with key of `std::string` and maybe multiple printable types.

So you can use polymorphism here, don't use `void *`, create an interface (An interface in C++ is a normal class/struct with abstract methods) called Printable for example, then make your map as this map> or map> or map>, or even map a string to raw pointer of Printable (not recommended). Make your class have a virtual printableString function, then make a friend operator << function to ostream where you can `cout << printableString()`

***Example:***

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

class Printable {
public:
    virtual std::string printableString() const = 0;
    friend ostream &operator << (ostream &stream, const Printable &printable) {
        return stream << printable.printableString();
    }
};

class PrintableString: public Printable {
private:
    std::string string;
public:
    PrintableString(std::string string): string(string) {}
    virtual std::string printableString() const {
        return string;
    }
};

map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Printable>> ptr;
int main() {
    ptr["Aaaa"] = std::make_shared<PrintableString>("B");
    cout << *(ptr["Aaaa"]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OP's question is about accessing a `void *`. I agree that polymorphism is one common way of solving dynamic dispatching, but this is not the problem stated by OP.

Answer (score 0):

> But if i don't know the data type how will i print?

`void *` is an opaque type. You have to know, somehow, the actual type behind it. Otherwise, you can't dereference it.

For instance, you can carry the information in an `enum` variable carrying which type it is, and then you run different printing code depending on that.

---

Alternatively, if you at least knew the size of the object behind the `void *`, you could print the raw bytes (casting to `char *`).

Comment: **you could print the raw bytes (casting to char *)**,  How? If it is a pointer to integer for example this is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @user9335240 It isn't. See [basic.lval]p8.8 of the standard.

Comment: If you limit it by size, yes it is not undefined,  but the printed string would be not human readable. But if it is not limited by size, the system will keep printing characters until a null is reached, which is undefined.

Comment: @user9335240 There is no string here. The `char *` simply points to the memory where the other object lives. As pointed out by the answer, you need to use the size to iterate through it (and do whatever you want with it for printing).